# Hadoop slave files configuration

Tags: hadoop

So I have a master and 3 slave machines and the `slaves` file on master machine has following entries:

```
master
slave1
slave2
slave3
```

Do I have to place this same slaves file in all of the slave machines or should i remove the first line having master and then place in slave machines?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The conf/master file corresponds to the Secondary Name Node and conf/slaves files corresponds to the TaskTracker/DataNode. Based on the cluster configurations [pseudo distributed](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) or [fully distributed](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/), the master/slave file configuration changes. When running in pseudo distributed mode, the master/slaves will have localhost and in fully distributed mode they will have the appropriate hostnames.

These files need to be present in the masters and not on the slaves. Check the Apache [documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html#Hadoop_Startup) on the purpose of the master/slaves configuration files, this will make it clear where to place the files.

Comment: I have a fully distributed cluster. So you mean to say that slaves file do not need to be present in conf folder of hadoop installation in slave machines?

Comment: yes - it's not required - no harm in keeping it also - make sure you have DNS setup or add the proper entries in the /etc/hosts file for the host to ip mapping.

Comment: The documentation reference is dangling.

Comment: Current versions (2.7.x for sure) don't use the `masters` file anymore. You can instead specify the Secondary Name Node using the configuration `dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address`. See [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml) for more.

Answer (score 0):

slave files are still needed

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.5/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html

Slaves File

List all slave hostnames or IP addresses in your etc/hadoop/slaves file, one per line. Helper scripts (described below) will use the etc/hadoop/slaves file to run commands on many hosts at once. It is not used for any of the Java-based Hadoop configuration. In order to use this functionality, ssh trusts (via either passphraseless ssh or some other means, such as Kerberos) must be established for the accounts used to run Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

I've just faiced the same problem and fortunately it can be solved this way (same answer than [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66430902/7058363)):

1. Customize the `core-site.xml` file to point to the master node (in my case it has an alias named *nodemaster*). This file **must be in master and workers nodes**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <configuration>
        <property>
            <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
            <value>hdfs://nodemaster:9000</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>fs.default.name</name>
            <value>hdfs://nodemaster:9000</value>
        </property>
    </configuration>
</configuration>
```

2. That's all! Now when you run:

```
start-dfs.sh
start-yarn.sh
```

I'll connect to the master automatically