# Hadoop. How to avoid workers file due to Docker automatic names

Tags: docker, hadoop, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Some tools like Hadoop need to explicitly especify the name of workers (section *Slaves File* in [docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html)), but when deploys with Docker Swarm it assigns automatic container names, so workers file doesn't work anymore as the names in it don't exist. Is there any way to avoid this file or, at least, assign aliases for containers (independently of container name) to make it work?

Maybe I can't use `docker-compose.yml` file and I must create the services manually over the cluster... Any kind of light on the subject would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Hadoop documentation sucks... Apparently if you set the alias of master node  in the `core-site.xml` file you can omit the `workers` file. These are the step I followed:

1. Customized the `core-site.xml` file (in my `docker-compose.yml` file I put my master service with the name *nodemaster*). This file **must be in master and workers nodes**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <configuration>
        <property>
            <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
            <value>hdfs://nodemaster:9000</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>fs.default.name</name>
            <value>hdfs://nodemaster:9000</value>
        </property>
    </configuration>
</configuration>
```

2. Now when you run:

```
start-dfs.sh
start-yarn.sh
```

I'll connect to the master automatically